# Why are the user profile icons showing as [?]

Tags: support

I notice that in the profile bar the icon I uploaded appears, but when I go to questions, the profile image I uploaded, as well as most (but not all) other members who have answered questions are now showing up as an unfound image [?] icon in Safari.  Is that temporary? Why are some user's images showing up but not others? Is a resolution in the works? Is there anything we can do on our end to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem at SO's end? Those images are hosted at imgur, is that blocked e.g. at your work (this has happened to me before now)?

Comment: Aparrently, it's a Avatarocalypse.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ... It's odd. When I look at the black menu bar above the forum, I see the icon I uploaded. Just not in the profile section in answers to questions. Why would it show up in the one place and not others? I just visited imgur main page and see all the pics there. Not on an office computer behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: same problem here, problem is images are now served as https http://i.stack.imgur.com/v2K29.png

Comment: Same, on personal WiFi.  Apparently imgur has an issue with https?

Comment: @rlemon yikes. I see the big pic, but also many borked image links in that picture.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.

Comment: @nerdistcolony it seems to only affect  the people who use imgur for their profile source.

Comment: Why do pics have to be secured over https anyway?

Comment: Gravatar is OK.

Comment: workaround (sadly needs to be run on every page load) `[].forEach.call(document.images,img=>{ if( /imgur/.test(img.src) ) { img.src = img.src.replace(/https/,'http'); } })`

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/659502523124981760 and now we wait..

Comment: Now I can reproduce it, not loading any imgur images.

Comment: It just stared working again for me.

Answer (score 10):

This is being caused by an SSL issue. The links to the images are using `https` and the certificate is valid enough all the way up to the hostname. Looks like whoever set this up did not renew the cert for i.stack.imgur.com (if it always existed like this to begin with).

[SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=i.stack.imgur.com)

**Hostname of images**: i.stack.imgur.com

**Cert Hostname**: ssl330558.cloudflaressl.com

---

- One possible scenario:

  The certificate was purchased through Cloudflare a few days back (based on the issue date and common name) and then a change was made for images to use https, but the hostname on the cert was not correct.
- Another possible scenario

  This is somehow managed from cloudflares side and they borked it (i don't know how it could be however)
- Another possible scenario

  Someone renewed it for the wrong hostname by accident.

Comment: It's worse than just an SSL issue... If you accept the invalid cert, you get a 403 forbidden from CloudFlare - so looks like the whole `i.stack.imgur.com` subdomain might be having issues

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend accepting the self signed cert. For a lot of reasons. Main reason why I did not give a direct link to it

Comment: For the record, it's not self-signed, it's a genuine COMODO cert, just for a different hostname. Most likely, it's genuine for the CloudFlare server hosting the imgur content. If the imgur subdomain isn't configured for Https, it would fall back to the stock 403 forbidden. In any case, I agree it's not something everyone should do, but ignoring a cert temporarily to examine content poses no risk if you assume the content might be tampered with.